# Javascript for-loop not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing unexpected behavior in my javascript (which leverages [jquery.tile.js](https://urin.github.io/jquery.tile.js/)). This part is working:

```
  $(function(){
      var minWidth = 450;
      if (minWidth <= $(window).width()) {
        $('.tile-portfolio').tile(3);
        $(window).load(function() {
          $('tile-portfolio').tile(3);
        });
   }
     });
```

...but this part is *not* working:

```
var tile = [ '.tile-portfolio', ".tile-blog", ".tile-qiita" ];

for (var i = 0, i < tile.length; i++) {
  $.function(){
    $(tile[i]).tile(3);
    $(window).load(function() {
      $(tile[i]).tile(3);
    });
});
```

}

Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Comment: You have a comma instead of a semi colon in the loop.

Comment: The "not working" version has a variety of syntax errors.  I suggest you look at the error console when something is "not working".  It's actively trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Oh God, why not just `$('.tile-portfolio, .tile-blog, .tile-qiita').tile(3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an error in your loop and in your use of jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0, i < tile.length; i++) {  // , instead of ;
  $.function(){                          // $. instead of $(
    $(tile[i]).tile(3);
```

Change it to:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
    $(function(){
          // ...
      })
```

Those are both syntax errors that prevent your code from running at all.
Open the console in your browser's developer tools and you should see a `Syntax error`.

`$` is a function *and* an object, but a function object is not a valid key for an object property, so `object.function() {...` will always be invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the comma `,` by semi-colon `;` in `for` loop definition :

```
for (var i = 0, i < tile.length; i++) {
______________^
```

Should be :

```
for (var i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it doesn't work because when the second code block hits the `$(window).load()` handler, `i` no longer has the value you expect it to have: it was defined by the loop, which has since completed, so `i` has a value of 3.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  //this line won't be what you expect
  //because this is an asynchronous event handler method
  $(tile[i]).tile(3);
  //check by doing this:
  alert("i at this point is: " + i);
});
```